# Using a list of column names to do operations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Say I have a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                    "B1": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                    "C1": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52],
                    "A2": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                    "B2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                    "C2": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]})
col1_names = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']
col2_names = ['A2', 'B2', 'C2']
col_new = ['delA', 'delB', 'delC']
```

I would like to do an operation where I get three new columns in df with values corresponding to the difference between col2_names and col1_names.

```py
for i in range(len(col1_names)):
    df[col_new[i]] = df[col2_names[i]] - df[col1_names[i]]
```

Is there a way to vectorize and do it without a loop?

Tried this:

```py
df[col_new] = df[col2_names] - df[col1_names]
```

Expected same result as the above loop solution but I get `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`.

Additional: can this be generalized to other operations?

Comment: I'm sure there are other more pythonic responses, but the following will do what you are looking for. `pd.DataFrame(df[col2_names].values- df[col1_names].values, columns=col_new)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are performing operations on data frames, they will align their indices. Row labels are matched to row labels and same with column labels. `col1_names` and `col2_names` have nothing in common so you get all NA.

Try this:

```py
df[col_new] = df[col2_names].values - df[col1_names].values
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my question! When you say "col1_names and col2_names have nothing in common so you get all NA." what would having something in common between column names look like?

Comment: The common columns will show the numeric values, as expected

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
col1 = df.filter(like='1').columns
col2 = df.filter(like='2').columns
out = df.join(df[col1].rename(lambda x: 'del' + x[:-1], axis=1)\
                      .sub(df[col2].rename(lambda x: 'del' + x[:-1], axis=1)))
```

out:

```
    A1  B1  C1  A2  B2  C2  delA    delB    delC
0   10  13  17  10  13  17  0       0       0
1   20  23  27  20  23  27  0       0       0
2   15  18  22  15  18  22  0       0       0
3   30  33  37  30  33  37  0       0       0
4   45  48  52  45  48  52  0       0       0
```